# how can i make the vertical line on the text disappear when it finish

Tags: html, css

I use this code to make the text look like it is being written, on the moment when the user enters the website.

I want to continue to show the animation of writing when finished, that's when a want to hide the vertical line (cursor).

```css
body{background:blue;}
.line {
      width: 4;
      top: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.anim-typewriter {
      animation: typewriter 3s steps(40) 1s 1 normal both,
      blinkTextCussor 500ms steps(40) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
      from {
            width: 0;
      }
      to {
            width: 9em;
      }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
      @keyframes typewriter {
            from {
                  width: 0;
            }
            to {
                  width: 9em;
                  
            }
      }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCussor {
      from {
            border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      }
      to {
            border-right-color: transparent;
            
            
            
            
      }
}
```

```html
<div class="line anim-typewriter">Your Best Automation</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If  you make the blinking cursor run for just a bit more than the text 'reveal' and also give it `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, when it has finished it will stick at the `opacity: 0` it gathered from the end of its animation.

```css
body{background:blue;}
.line {
      width: 4;
      top: 50%;
      margin: auto;
      border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.anim-typewriter {
      animation: typewriter 3s steps(40) 1s 1 normal both,
      blinkTextCussor 500ms steps(40) 4s forwards;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
      from {
            width: 0;
      }
      to {
            width: 9em;
      }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
      @keyframes typewriter {
            from {
                  width: 0;
            }
            to {
                  width: 9em;
                  
            }
      }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCussor {
      from {
            border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
      }
      to {
            border-right-color: transparent;
            
            
            
            
      }
}

*i want to continue show the animation of writing when the first part finish thats why a want to hide the vertical line *
```

```html
<div class="line anim-typewriter">Your Best Automation</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify, if you can (want to) use javascript but you can set event listener for the `animationend` and let the vertical line disappear when it triggers (or stop the animation first and add nice fade-out effect).

```js
const typewriter = document.querySelector(".anim-typewriter");

console.log(typewriter)

typewriter.addEventListener("animationend", function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    typewriter.style.border = "0px";
  }, 600);



}, false);
```

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}

.line {
  width: 4;
  top: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.anim-typewriter {
  animation: typewriter 3s steps(40) 1s 1 normal both, blinkTextCussor 500ms steps(40) infinite normal;
}

@keyframes typewriter {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 9em;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  @keyframes typewriter {
    from {
      width: 0;
    }
    to {
      width: 9em;
    }
  }
}

@keyframes blinkTextCussor {
  from {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  }
  to {
    border-right-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line anim-typewriter">Your Best Automation</div>
```